# Как рисовать по контролах на panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть panel и на ней много кнопочек, надписей и тд...(все они создаются динамически) так как мне все-таки надо рисовать по панели и чтоби линия била и по кнопках и тд... вот пример с картинками https://qna.habr.com/q/961311?e=11007537#clarification_1188385, как рисовать по контролах которые находятся на panel в событии paint(для panel)???

Comment: Windows Forms не поддерживает прозрачный фон.

Comment: Может, просто убрать эту панель вообще?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  [нельзя ну может можно, но для моего решения нельзя либо искать другое решение](https://qna.habr.com/q/961311?e=11007537#clarification_1188385)

Comment: Ещё раз: если вам нужно, чтобы панель не загораживала контролы, то, как вариант, просто уберите эту панель. | По ссылке, которую вы привели, вопрос про _рисование_ поверх других контролов. Вам именно это нужно? Тогда почему вы спрашиваете совсем другое? Задайте вопрос именно про реальную задачу: "Как рисовать поверх контролов?"

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Полностю изменил вопрос

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213270/how-to-set-z-order-of-a-control-using-winforms меняете z order, и рисуете на панели...

Comment: @こきん А какже по кнонтролах или там все можно. Как етим воспользоваться????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С некоторыми ухищрениями, но создать прозрачную панель в WinForms можно.

Пример взят [отсюда](https://web.archive.org/web/20141227200000/http://bobpowell.net/transcontrols.aspx). Жаль Bob Powell удалил своей сайт. Хорошо, что хотя бы в архиве он сохранился.

```
public class TransparentPanel : Panel
{
    Timer _timer;

    public TransparentPanel()
    {
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        _timer.Interval = 100;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InvalidateEx();
    }        

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; // WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected void InvalidateEx()
    {
        if (Parent == null)
            return;

        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
        Parent.Invalidate(rc, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        // Do not allow the background to be painted.
    }
}
```

К сожалению, всё нарисованное на графиксе этой панели будет периодически мерцать.
К тому же, эта панель непрозрачна для кликов мышки.

---

Другой способ.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TextBox textBox;
        Button button;

        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();

            textBox = new TextBox { Parent = this, Text = "Some text" };
            button = new Button { Parent = this, Top = 30, Text = "Click" };

            DrawEllipse(new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 100), Color.Red, 5);
            DrawEllipse(new Rectangle(30, 30, 100, 50), Color.Green, 10);
        }

        private void DrawEllipse(Rectangle rectangle, Color color, int width)
        {
            var path = new GraphicsPath();
            path.AddEllipse(rectangle);
            rectangle.Inflate(-width, -width);
            path.AddEllipse(rectangle);

            var panel = new Panel
            {
                Parent = this,
                BackColor = color,
                Region = new Region(path)
            };

            panel.BringToFront();
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь мы меняем форму самого контрола (панели), задавая ему свойство `Region`.

По аналогии можно создать методы для рисования линий, прямоугольников и пр.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно поиграться с расположением элементов.
Вот пример:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62287606/how-to-set-a-transparent-winform-into-a-panel-transparent-panel-to-show-as-bac