# c# Нарисовать границы формы

Tags: c#, графика, рисование

Всем привет. Хочу нарисовать "кастомные" границы для формы (borderstyle стоит none). Форм у меня достаточно много, поэтому я подумал, что будет проще, если я создам метод, в который буду передавать форму. Написал я значит его (ниже код):

```
class BorderClass
    {
        public static void Paint(Form form)
        {
            using (Graphics gr = form.CreateGraphics())
            {
                Point p1 = new Point(0, 0); //левый верхний угол
                Point p2 = new Point(form.Size.Width, form.Size.Height); //правый верхний угол
                Point p3 = new Point(0, form.Size.Height); //левый нижний угол
                Point p4 = new Point(form.Size.Width, 0); //правый нижний угол
                Pen PenSettings = new Pen(Color.Red, 10);// цвет линии и ширина
                PenSettings.Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset;
                gr.DrawLine(PenSettings, p1, p4);// рисуем линию
            }
        }
    }
```

В Form_Load пытаюсь вызвать его: " `BorderClass.Paint(this);` " , но как-то не очень получается.

p.s. для примера взял точки 1 и 4, чтобы наглядно было видно, что это работает, но оно не работает. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: `но как-то не очень получается` как вы это поняли?

Comment: На форме нет линии... думаю, толстую красную линию я-бы заметил, а тут та же форма, что и была

Comment: Линия рисуется, но тут же затирается при обновлении формы. Базовое правило: рисовать на любом контроле можно только в **событии** [Paint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint?view=net-5.0). Подпишите форму на это событие, а внутри него вызывайте свой метод. У метода будет параметр `Graphics`. Передавать, соответственно, нужно `e.Graphics`.

Comment: А можно как-нибудь переопределить метод OnPaint во всех формах? p.s. попробовал создать событие Paint, в него впихнуть метод, но всё равно ничего не получилось. Самое интересное - если создать кнопку и при нажатии на эту кнопку вызвать событие - то всё работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс-хелпер для рисования бордюра:

```
class FormBorderRenderer
{
    static Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 10) { Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset };

    public static void Draw(Form form, Graphics graphics)
    {
        graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, form.ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```

Я переименовал и класс, и метод, чтобы он больше соответствовал уже имеющимся в WinForms классам наподобие `TextBoxRenderer`, `ButtonRenderer` и т. п.

Перо сделано полем, чтобы не создавать его каждый раз заново.
Если его создавать при каждом вызове метода, то нужно вызывать `Dispose` для освобождения ресурсов, а лучше - обернуть в `using`.

Вместо параметра `Form` метод может принимать `Rectangle`, если для отрисовки не нужны другие свойства формы.

---

Я использовал `ClientRectangle`, но это по желанию.
Полезная ссылка: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34453825/5045688 - различие между `ClientRectangle` и `DisplayRectangle`.

---

Форму подписываем на событие `Paint`, в обработчике которого пишем:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    FormBorderRenderer.Draw(this, e.Graphics);
}
```

---

---

> А можно как-нибудь переопределить метод OnPaint во всех формах?

Базовый класс формы с произвольной отрисовкой бордюра:

```
public class CustomBorderForm : Form
{
    public CustomBorderForm()
    {
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        FormBorderRenderer.Draw(this, e.Graphics);
    }
}
```

Далее наследуем другие формы от него:

```
public partial class Form1 : CustomBorderForm
```

---

Предложу ещё один вариант.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        //InitializeComponent();

        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        BackColor = Color.Red;

        var panel = new Panel
        {
            Parent = this,
            BackColor = SystemColors.Control,
            Left = 10,
            Top = 10,
            Width = this.Width - 20,
            Height = this.Height - 20
        };

        var button = new Button { Parent = panel, Text = "Click" };
    }
}
```

Задаём форме фоновый цвет - это будет цвет бордюра.
Помещаем на форму панель, с размерами меньше на требуемую толщину бордюра.

Теперь все контролы помещаем на эту панель. Не на форму!

Comment: Немного не понял момент с наследованием customborderform. Я так понял, если наследуем форму, то всё равно нужно подписывать на событие? Просто, в кастомном классе уже прописан override, поэтому....можно чисто теоретически просто заменить Form на CustomBorderForm, так?

Comment: А, и ещё одна проблема возникла. Создал пустую форму - всё отрисовывается. Попробовал на своём проекте - нет. Заметил такую штуку, что эта линия рисуется снизу всех элементов. Можно ли её как-нибудь переместить на передний план?

Comment: @Frehzy - подписываться на событие не надо, т. к. отрисовка уже реализована в базовой форме.

Comment: @Frehzy - переместить линию на передний план нельзя. Она рисуется на фоне.

Comment: А можно ли как-нибудь тогда расположить поверх формы прозрачную панель, на которой будет отрисовываться это?

Comment: @Frenzy - не спрашивайте в комментариях, задавайте новые вопросы. / Забудьте о прозрачности в WinForms - там с этим всё плохо. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1262639/184217 - пример прозрачной панели (но в любом случае он глючный)

Comment: @Frehzy - конечная цель всего этого какая? Вы хотели форму с собственной рамкой - вы её получили. Теперь просто учитывайте толщину этой рамки при добавлении контролов на форму.

Comment: @Frehzy - добавил ещё один вариант