# Как сделать, чтобы один label был перекрыт другим label но всё еще был виден за ним?

Tags: c#, winforms

Когда я ставлю label2 повверх label1 в форме получается это: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне же нужно чтобы label2 всё еще перекрывал label1, но label1 был виден под label2, как на этой картинке: [image]

Прозрачный бэкграунд не помогает.

Comment: А добиться то вы чего хотите? Опишите, пожалуйста

Comment: Я прикрепил картинку

Comment: ВинФормы малопригодны для прозрачностей и т. п. Можете попробовать код отсюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1262639/184217 (Panel заменить на Label). Но лучше выводить текст с помощью [TextRenderer.DrawText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) или [Graphics.DrawString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

Comment: В винформах без костылей не получится, это одна из причин, почему я когда-то ушел в WPF.

Comment: Большое спасибо!